# Figuring out if pathname starts with u

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

```
$(function() {
   var s = $('#field_id5 div.field_uneditable').html();
     if(s == "+Member") {
       var path = window.location.pathname;
 if( /^u\d+/.test(path) ){
    $('#content').prependTo('#container').css('marginRight','0px');
    $('#page_wrapper').remove();
   }
 $('#profile-advance-left').hide();
   }
});
```

getting error Uncaught **ReferenceError: pathname is not defined**

UPDATED CODE ABOVE---

The code above for `var numbers` I tried writing a regex sort of thing(not very experienced in regex) where it would check if the numbers were after u. The code works in the sense except its checking if u is in the pathname at all. I only want it to check if starts with u, because I have a link like so `/forum` and this code is ran which is not what I want at all. I need this code to only run on urls like so

`/u1`

`/u2`

`/u3`

`/u4`

Any suggestions?

Ok so both answers below are still not working.. A friend of mine gave me a code, yet I don't believe it is escaped please take a look

```
if(//?ud+/.test(window.location.pathname)){
  $('#content').prependTo('#container').css('marginRight','0px');
   $('#page_wrapper').remove();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I only want it to check if starts with u

```
if( window.location.pathname.indexOf('u') == 0 ) ...
```

or

```
if( /^u/.test(window.location.pathname) )...
```

If you need to ensure the `u` is followed by 1 or more digits, I would do this:

```
if( /^u\d+/.test(window.location.pathname) ) ...
```

The entire code snippet would be:

```
if( /^u\d+/.test(window.location.pathname) ){
  $('#content').prependTo('#container').css('marginRight','0px');
  $('#page_wrapper').remove();
}
```

Comment: Hey Kyle, does .test need to be after the regex? Also should I get rid of the `var checkif = pathname+numbers`?

Comment: I have this right now...

`var pathname = window.location.pathname;`  
`var regex =/^u[0-9]*/;`  
`var reg = regex.test(pathname);`  
`if(reg) {//code follows`

Comment: Could I clean it up with vars? like I have above?

Comment: See my other edit. I have an example of your entire code snippet cleaned up.

Comment: ok kyle, I get an error. I will post with my follow up in the first post ok. give me one minute. if all is said and done without error you'll get my check mark i mean

Comment: It is working for me so I would assume you have some other error.

Comment: Hmm not sure really. I posted my script above

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = /^u[0-9][0-9]*/;
regex.test(checkif);
```

This will test if it's in the format "u" + series of digits

EDIT: fixed the regex function according to Kyle's comment. There's probably a more concise way of doing it, but it should work.

Comment: this would match "u". The `*` is allowing zero or more digits. Also, there is no need for a character class for the `u` character. `/^u[0-9]*/` is the same as what you have.

Comment: Ok anthony, since I am new and don't write regex all that much. can you explain the code at hand. `//` is usually where the regex is written correct? `^`is what starts with or contains? `[u]`is what I am looking for followed by `[0-9]`and the `*`is what?

Comment: @Kyle: ah, yeah, that's true. Good call. Fixed it.

Comment: @EasyBB: Yes, the /s say that it is a regex object, like the 's or "s say that it is a string object. ^ means string start, [0-9] means any digit 0-9, and the * means any amount of the preceding set (in this case [0-9]) from 0 to infinity. I've fixed it now so that there must be at least one instance of [0-9]

Comment: Thanks anthony_mcdougle, just like I posted above though I am getting error?

Comment: Ok fixed error. I had pathname set before, and when I deleted it or whatever it caused the code to not work, plus it was outside the scope of the code :/ haha told you